# letsencrypt/certbot systemd timer/service not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, letsencrypt, certbot

I installed certbot for nginx and the autorenew script set itself up automatically, but this is the email I receive, whenever it runs:

`/home/foobar/certbot-renew.sh: 1: /home/foobar/certbot-renew.sh: /usr/bin/certbot: not found`

What confuses me is, there's no `certbot-renew.sh` in my home dir...?

Further information from `systemctl`:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run certbot twice daily

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,12:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=43200
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

and

```
# /lib/systemd/system/certbot.service
[Unit]
Description=Certbot
Documentation=file:///usr/share/doc/python-certbot-doc/html/index.html
Documentation=https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/certbot -q renew
PrivateTmp=true
```

I'm new to using systemd, help is appreciated!

## Edit:

As @grawity suggested, I checked my crontabs instead and found this:

```
foo@bar:~$ cat /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Also this:

```
foo@bar:~$ cat /etc/cron.d/certbot
# /etc/cron.d/certbot: crontab entries for the certbot package
#
# Upstream recommends attempting renewal twice a day
#
# Eventually, this will be an opportunity to validate certificates
# haven't been revoked, etc.  Renewal will only occur if expiration
# is within 30 days.
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew
```

To clarify:

```
foo@bar:~$ which certbot
/usr/bin/certbot

foo@bar:~$ certbot --version
certbot 0.26.1
```

Answer (score 6):

Certbot has its own service to renew things, you do not need no additional crontab lines. In theory.

Practically I've seed `certbot.timer` stopping seeming for no reason at all:

```
$ sudo systemctl status certbot.timer
● certbot.timer - Run certbot twice daily
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since .....; 1 months 7 days ago
```

In that case restarting it helps:

```
sudo systemctl enable certbot.timer
sudo systemctl start certbot.timer
```

The reason why it stops functioning is yet to be found.

Comment: This happened to me recently, where auto-renew did not run, though the system has been doing so for years. Maybe a package update broke something. Anyway, kicking the timer fixed it.

Comment: Note; I use the Python PIP version of certbot on a few machines. If you ever installed certbot via APT and later remove it, the certbot.timer may still exist, but is in a 'masked' state. Please be aware you will need to create your own renew script in this case regardless of the presence of a systemd timer. Just edit the apt `/etc/cron.d/certbot` version to your liking (remove the systemd test check).

Answer (score 1):

Systemd services do not generate email notifications. Cron jobs do.

All of this indicates that your shown systemd units are not related to the problem (it's possible that they already work without problems) – but the same task is being done from *another* place; most likely a job defined in your *crontab*.

Use `crontab -l` to list cron jobs for your user account and `crontab -e` to edit them.

Make sure to check your own crontab, root's crontab (via sudo), *and* the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file (no special command for that one).

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that. I still don't know what's wrong, so I edited my question above with some additional info. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Older question, but may help others re: cron vs systemd and certbot:

You mention an "autorenew script set itself up automatically".
You mention "whenever it runs".
Since you seem to be aware something runs, what runs?
How did you install certbot under Ubuntu? APT?
`certbot-renew.sh` is NOT installed by certbot via APT (or SNAP). Never heard of it.

--

It looks like you installed certbot via APT since you have a /etc/cron.d file for certbot.

You first need to understand what the `/etc/cron.d/certbot` is actually doing (or not doing in your case):

`0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew` :

`0 */12 * * *` = Run this entry every 12 hours (on 12th hour).
`root` is user to run as.
`test` is used to see if `/usr/bin/certbot` is executable (by root) **AND** `systemd/system` does **NOT** (\!) exist.

If the test command passes/is true on both items then the next command (perl sleep) is executed. If perl sleep executes/exits properly, then the next command (certbot) is finally run.

**In your case, it never gets past the systemd check:**

The test command will fail. Your system DOES have systemd.
**Everything following the `&&` is NOT executed since `systemd/system` exists.**
Therefore, the `perl sleep` and `certbot` commands are NEVER run (via cron).

(If you didn't have systemd, then `test` would pass and perl sleep would set a random delay within the next 12 hour period (43200 seconds) and then run `certbot renew` (quietly).

As suggested, I would search your OWN crontab (and root's) for the script you may have added. **Not just the system-wide `/etc/crontab` you show.**

`sudo grep -R "certbot-renew.sh" /var/spool/cron/crontabs`

That ^ command may find the problem in your case. (It searches **all** user crontabs) If you find it, become that user, edit the file as mentioned (`crontab -e`) and remove that script.

You have shown no proof (a `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log` error on renew for instance) to show renewal is not working via systemd. Your systemd certbot files look fine.

To see if your systemd certbot timer is running use this:

`systemctl status certbot.timer`

Example output you should see:

```
● certbot.timer - Run certbot twice daily
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (waiting) since Thu 2020-12-03 12:28:04 CST; 3 weeks 5 days ago
  Trigger: Tue 2020-12-29 22:19:13 CST; 3h 14min left
```

To review recent log entries:

`journalctl -u certbot.service`
(or timer)

Let systemd do it's thing and renew them. No extra scripts or cron jobs needed.